# Ampps 3.7 not running with php 7.1

Tags: php, ampps

I'm using ampps 3.5 for make my Laravel project but my colleague add a library from github and it needs PHP 7.1 for setting. So I download ampps 3.7 and setup in my desktop but when using ampps 3.7, if I change version PHP to 7.1 then Apache will not running, if I change PHP to 7.0 then Apache running as nomally.
How can fix this bug?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by inserting the folder path (C:\Program Files(x86)\Ampps\php-7.1 as environment variable in windows 10 and then clicking on the "restore default configuration" button to get a refresh.

Answer (score 0):

[Softaculous Ampps 3.8 Apache not starting if i change PHP version to 7.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52923594/softaculous-ampps-3-8-apache-not-starting-if-i-change-php-version-to-7-1/55156722#55156722)

For windows10 OS***

This is how I got it to run.
But yeah, make sure php is in your environment variables as previously mentioned.

"AMPPS - It won’t run PHP 7.1 with out changing the executables to run as administrator mode. Apache will terminate without an error. I believe this is because even if AMPPS is running in admin priviledges these are not granted to the php.exe when it is run. Go to the file location of php.exe, right click and click on properties, click the compatibility tab and select the check box for ‘run as administrator’. Do the same for the httpd.exe under apache->bin->httpd.exe. (Not sure if the httpd priviledge change matters but I did it and it worked.)

Run AMPPS and hopefully like me, your php/apache problems are gone."

Comment: Make sure to add the important parts from the link in your answer, so that your post has value even if the link becomes broken or changed. ([From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review))