# Softaculous Ampps 3.8 Apache not starting if i change PHP version to 7.1

Tags: php, windows, apache, ampps

I have a recent problem in Ampps Software on Windows 10, Apache stopping automatically if PHP version is 7.1 but if I change back PHP Version to 5.6 it's working fine

and here's the error log for Apache

```html
<pre>

[Mon Oct 22 10:28:12.413768 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 12484:tid 684] AH00455: Apache/2.4.27 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.1.0f PHP/5.6.31 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Oct 22 10:28:12.413768 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 12484:tid 684] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC15 Server built: Jul  7 2017 11:43:51
[Mon Oct 22 10:28:12.413768 2018] [core:notice] [pid 12484:tid 684] AH00094: Command line: 'apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d D:/Ampps/apache'
[Mon Oct 22 10:28:12.417758 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 12484:tid 684] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 5924
[Mon Oct 22 10:28:13.307885 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5924:tid 740] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Mon Oct 22 10:28:45.068164 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 9816:tid 700] AH00455: Apache/2.4.27 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.1.0f PHP/7.1.8 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Oct 22 10:28:45.068164 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 9816:tid 700] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC15 Server built: Jul  7 2017 11:43:51
[Mon Oct 22 10:28:45.068164 2018] [core:notice] [pid 9816:tid 700] AH00094: Command line: 'apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d D:/Ampps/apache'
[Mon Oct 22 10:28:45.070158 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 9816:tid 700] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 15180
[Mon Oct 22 10:28:47.563384 2018] [mpm_winnt:crit] [pid 9816:tid 700] AH00419: master_main: create child process failed. Exiting.

</pre>
```

I didn't change anything or install anything new, and I reinstalled it many times and tried XAMPP it's working fine

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its solved by disabling Ioncube loader extension for me,  Thanks for all replies

Comment: PHP extensions are built for specific major versions of PHP, such as 5.6, 7.1, 7.2 etc. When you update PHP you must ensure that you also update 3rd party extensions such as ionCube, NewRelic etc. For ionCube you just get the relevant one from https://www.ioncube.com/loaders.php and use the Loader Wizard script for guidance if unsure on what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the php version used by AMPPS by following their guide here ->
http://www.ampps.com/wiki/How_to_change_php_version

In the AMPPS control panel, select options and then select change php version. The changed version should now be displayed in the control panel.

Comment: I'm using this way to change the PHP version already but after I choose 7.1 Apache not starting and return the same error in Apache log file "AH00419: master_main: create child process failed. Exiting."

Comment: with this line here ->[Mon Oct 22 10:28:45.068164 2018] [core:notice] [pid 9816:tid 700] AH00094: Command line: 'apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d D:/Ampps/apache' -- It seems as if you need to install this - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads

Comment: out of curiosity, are you able to run "php -v" in your cmd without the ampps running?

Comment: "'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file." > even with Ampps same response

Comment: But now after i reinstall vc_redist apache working but after 3 times it's working statically i mean when i start Ampps Software i should start apache and start again 3 times til apache working statically !!!!

Comment: vc_redist needed to be installed before installing ampps

Comment: yes, vs_redist installed already before I install Ampps, so what's your suggestion to try? is that child coming in error log is linked to vs_redist ? because i can't understand actually the error log.

Comment: it could be any number of things, the process starts, and then fails. no other errors are thrown during that time. Another thing to try is disabling your firewall, and if that doesn't work, try running "netsh winsock RESET" in cmd. Other than those, its a brick wall.

Answer (score 0):

Try run **httpd.exe** with as administrator and it worked.

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\apache\bin

Comment: Your reply is not an answer.

Comment: Worked for me. On windows "run as admin" ... no error.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is 4 months old, but I have had significant problems with PHP on windows and today I got this problem fixed.

AMPPS - It won’t run PHP 7.1 with out changing the executables to run as administrator mode. Apache will terminate without an error. I believe this is because even if AMPPS is running in admin priviledges these are not granted to the php.exe when it is run. Go to the file location of php.exe, right click and click on properties, click the compatibility tab and select the check box for ‘run as administrator’. Do the same for the httpd.exe under apache->bin->httpd.exe. (Not sure if the httpd priviledge change matters but I did it and it worked.)

Run AMPPS and hopefully like me, your php/apache problems are gone.

Answer (score 0):

i solved mine following steps below:

i switched PHP version to 5.6 which everything works normally,
then went to this URL:

http://localhost/ampps/index.php?

there i found some updates available
notification on top of the page below url bar on the page
if you see updates available for your php 7.0 7.1 ...
90% you will resolve this issue like mine
i tried update all available updates

then restart the ampps app
now working with PHP 7.1 great.

i hope it works for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but since i've been using Ampps for 5 years , i provide similar solutions for my common errors maybe someone find it useful .

- If you changed **Document Root** path in "httpd.conf" , make sure that folder still exists.
- If you see the logs about InnoDB files, follow the path and delete that dump files and logs.
- If you got this error "master_main: create child process failed" in log files :

  Change PHP version to 7.1 and Try this:

  Open AMPPS panel --> PHP --> Configuration.

  Search for the following line and comment it by adding ';' at the beginning of the line: zend_extension="{$path}\php-7.1\ioncube_loader_win_7.1.dll"